# Como regresar entre varias actividades Android

Tags: android

Tengo un problema espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Tengo varias actividades

ActividadPrincipal,
Actividad1,
Actividad2,
Actividad3

ActividadPrincipal digamos que es una lista y las actividades 1 al 3 son formularios, en la actividad3 cuando finaliza un guardado necesito regresar a la actividadPrincipal, pero si uso finish solo regreso a la anterior, no quiero usar startActivity por que cuando le den con el botón del teléfono "regresar" se regresaria a la Actividad3.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres primero tienes que indicar que tu actividad principal tendra solo una instancia utilizando el atributo `android:launchMode` en el `manifest.xml`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<activity
   android:name="..."
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   />
```

Entonces cuando necesites volver a tu actividad la invocas utilizando el metodo `startActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class );
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity( intent );
```

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` lo que hace es eliminar el stack de las activities activas.

Comment: Gracias funciono perfecto